# How to get product collection of a particular category depending upon the custom attribute value in magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options, products

I have created an attribute for product like enable/disable to show product in slider in frontend. How can i get the product collection of the product enabled for this attribute value using category id in magento 2

Comment: show us what you tried. give us some code and explain whats not working

Comment: what is your attribute type?

Comment: @Devidas Its YES/NO  see https://prnt.sc/sd031f Want to retrieve products based on this value and specific to category

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

I have created a block and set collection in this file and get in the template file.

I have got product collection in current category id and set best_seller custom attribute filter

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;

class Sandwich extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
    private $_registry;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryfactory
     */
    private $_categoryFactory;
    /**
     * @var Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession
     **/
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Config $pageConfig,
        Registry $registry,
        CategoryFactory $categoryfactory,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->pageConfig = $pageConfig;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryfactory;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    }
    /**
    *@return Array
    **/
    public function getCategoryProductAttributeData()
    {
        //Attribute best_sellers
        //1 = Yes
        //0 = No
        $category_load = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
        if($category_load):
            $categoryId = $category_load->getId();
            $category_product_collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
            $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $collection->addCategoryFilter($category_product_collection);
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('best_sellers',1);
            $collection->setPageSize(4);

            return $collection;

        endif;
    }
}
?>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: if you have any query feel free to ask me

Comment: Here why we are loading entire category? cant we pass just category id in filter?

Comment: you can pass category id in filter @Nafisa

Comment: @Devidad .. How?? then we need to load category collection?

Comment: i am getting this error Type Error occurred when creating object: Mageplaza\Productslider\Block\BestSellerProducts\Interceptor

Comment: try to remove var/ generated/ and then hit command upgrade deploy and flush cache then check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107751/discussion-between-nafisa-and-devidas).